# Create locked object

Tags: django, locking

Let's say I have a model class `Foo`. The structure doesn't matter.

I want:

```py
foo = Foo.objects.create(...)
# Do some stuff
foo.bar = "something"
foo.save()
```

This is, of course, unsafe, because another project can fetch the newly created `Foo` instance and modify it at the same time, with the final `save` overriding the one that happens earlier. Using `update_fields` can reduce the risk, but it is still there for processes that modify the same field (`bar`, in my example above).

A workaround for that is:

```py
foo = Foo.objects.create(...)
with transaction.atomic():
    foo = Foo.objects.select_for_update().get(pk=foo.pk)
    # Do some stuff
    foo.bar = "something"
    foo.save()
```

All good, except it feels a bit redundant to have to refetch the object that I already have.

Is there a way to

1. `select_for_update` when creating a new object, or to
2. `select_for_update` the `foo` itself after it was created, but without refetching it, or
3. is the above the best approach when one needs to create an object and then do some modifications after the fact?

Comment: Couldn't you just foo=Foo(field1=...) and then # do some stuff foo.bar = "something" foo.save() ?

Comment: Is it necessary for you to create the `Foo` instance before `# Do some stuff`? Could you move the creation till after "some stuff"? That way there would be just creation, no updated necessary.

Comment: No, I need it this way. The full example is complex, but I'm really just curious if and how this could be achieved.

Comment: One case where this is useful: populate parent with children. I don't want it done twice (from two processes), so I can lock the parent, add children, and unlock the parent, thus avoiding two parallel processes adding children twice.